# How to get OKTA implicit response without callback (Desktop app)

Tags: okta, okta-api

Can i get okta authentication worked in Desktop applications ? Where i just want to hit okta api to get access token and other details in response ? 
As per my understanding it looks for some redirect_uri which i do not have in case of desktop application. Any recommendation ?

I tried it with my web application that works fine. 
with following parameters

```
const openIdConnectUrl = 'https://xxxx.okta.com/oauth2/default';
const clientId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const redirectUri = 'http://xxxx.com/yyy/zzz';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reqeust

```
curl -v -X POST \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "username": "xxxx@example.com",
  "password": "xxxxxx",
  "relayState": "/myapp/some/deep/link/i/want/to/return/to",
  "options": {
    "multiOptionalFactorEnroll": false,
    "warnBeforePasswordExpired": false
  }
}' "https://${yourOktaDomain}/api/v1/authn"
```

provides response like

```
{"expiresAt":"2019-11-13T06:27:03.000Z","status":"SUCCESS","sessionToken":"20111PJIKs504fXVoLs-9zf4t8YoVzMCEvlUbcnjDnPhqSk7C-YPzCL","_embedded":{"user":{"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","passwordChanged":"2019-11-13T03:20:33.000Z","profile":{"login":"xxxxxx@gmail.com","firstName":"xxxx","lastName":"xxxx","locale":"en","timeZone":"America/Los_Angeles"}}},"_links":{"cancel":{"href":"https://dev-924234.okta.com/api/v1/authn/cancel","hints":{"allow":["POST"]}}}}
```

Refer the below documentation if needed.

https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/authn

Although it did not serve my purpose completely. But it can help you.